# non-conformable arrays error when multiplying two matrix (*%*)

Tags: r, random, normal-distribution

The next reproducible code generates 394 observations of 183 random normales, and tries to correlate them with Cholesky decomposition:

Generate the parameters

```
d <- 211

l <- 183

m <- -0.006495094

vectorsd <- rep(0.29, 183)
```

Generate random normals uncorrelated

```
rnormd <- as.data.frame(rnorm(l, mean = m, sd = vectorsd))

for (i in 1:(d+l))  {
  rnormd[,i] <- rnorm(l, mean = m, sd = vectorsd)
}
```

Generate a random semidefinite positive matrix of correlations

```
v <- runif(183,0.6,0.8)
corr <- `diag<-`(tcrossprod(v),1)
```

Generate cholesky matrix

```
cholesky <- chol(corr)
```

Correlate the normals and transpose the output

```
rnormd <- t(t(rnormd)%*%cholesky)
```

In this last instruction I get the error

> Error in rnormd * cholesky : non-conformable arrays

At first a thought that the problem was going to be solved transposing my cholesky matrix, but then I realized that `chol()` function already transposes it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What about `cholesky %*% as.matrix(rnormd)`?

Comment: `t(as.matrix(rnormd)) %*% cholesky` works fine.  You need to ensure (1) to use matrix multiplkication `%*%` not (`*`), and (2) that ncol of A equals nrow of B in `A %*% B`

Comment: @dww So, the problem is that it is not coerced automatically to a matrix format. It worked. upvoted

Comment: NP.  BTW why did you ever convert to data.frame in the first place?  Seems the whole calculation is better done with matrices

Comment: voting to close as a typo, since was simply down to performing matrix multiplication on a non-matrix

Answer (score -1):

If you want multiply two matrices you should use `%*%` instead of `*` sign. So here is the part you should fix.

```
rnormd <- t(t(rnormd)%*%cholesky)
```